# How to solve ImproperlyConfigured error during setting AUTH_USER_MODEL

Tags: django, django-models

My app directory is something like this

```
users(app name)
   |__models
        |__users.py
```

and my users.py has the model User like this:-

```
class User(BaseModel):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False)
    email_id = models.EmailField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'users'
```

I am trying to set AUTH_USER_MODEL in my settigns.py as

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
```

But I am getting this error

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to
>   model 'users.User' that has not been installed

Here is my installed_apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'rest_framework',
    'oauth2_provider',

    'users',
]
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: you have to add users app to installed apps

Comment: Its already there

Comment: place your model inside models.py , that is the convention

Comment: Yes, but this time I am supposed to do it this way only.

Comment: then you change the path of AUTH_USER_MODEL

Comment: I have trited that too. I am gettign the same error even if I provide the complete path of the model like users.models.users.User

Comment: @AartiJoshi can you show line where you install `users` app in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: I have just added installed_apps to my question